# Python: Equivalent of searchlines for characters/strings

Tags: python, search

I have a .txt doc full of text.  I'd like to search it for specific characters (or ideally groups of characters (strings) , then do things with the charcter found, and the characters 2 in front/4behind the selected characters.

I made a version that searches lines for the character, but I cant find the equivalent for characters.

```
f = open("C:\Users\Calum\Desktop\Robopipe\Programming\data2.txt", "r")
searchlines = f.readlines()
f.close()
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
  if "_" in line: 
    for l in searchlines[i:i+2]: print l, #if i+2 then prints line and the next
    print
```

Comment: use `str.find` if the substring exists it will give you the start index, it is easy to go two less and four after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem, what you want is to repeatedly search one giant string, instead of a searching a list of strings one by one.

So, the first step is, don't use `readlines`, use [`read`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read), so you get that one giant string in the first place.

Next, how do you repeatedly search for all matches in a string?

Well, a string is an iterable, just like a list is—it's an iterable of characters (which are themselves strings with length 1). So, you can just iterate over the string:

```
f = open(path)
searchstring = f.read()
f.close()
for i, ch in enumerate(searchstring):
    if ch == "_":
        print searchstring[i-4:i+2]
```

However, notice that this only works if you're only searching for a single-character match. And it will fail if you find a `_` in the first four characters. And it can be inefficient to loop over a few MB of text character by character.* So, you probably want to instead loop over [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find):

```
i = 4
while True:
    i = searchstring.find("_", i)
    if i == -1:
        break
    print searchstring[i-4:i+2]
```

<sub>* You may be wondering how `find` could possibly be doing anything but the same kind of loop. And you're right, it's still iterating character by character. But it's doing it in optimized code provided by the standard library—with the usual CPython implementation, this means the "inner loop" is in C code rather than Python code, it doesn't have to "box up" each character to test it, etc., so it can be much, much faster.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex for this:

The regex searches for any two characters (that are not _), an _, then any four characters that are not an underscore.

```
import re
with open(path) as f:
    searchstring = f.read()
regex = re.compile("([^_]{2}_[^_]{4})")
for match in regex.findall(searchstring):
    print match
```

With the input of:

```
hello_there my_wonderful_friend
```

The script returns:

```
lo_ther
my_wond
ul_frie
```